# Finding maximum value in column

Tags: r, max

My data is in column. I need to scan every 3 rows and come out with the maximum values. It's kind of moving average techniques but I dont want the data to be averaged. Maximum values is my major concern. 
e.g 29.66, 29.59, 30.05 = maximum is 30.05
then move to 29.59, 29.59, 30.05 = maximum is 30.05

How to do that in R-software?

```
29.66
29.59
30.05
29.59
29.59
30.05
29.59
29.92
30.26
30.18
30.47
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `rollapply` in the zoo package: `rollapply(x, 3, max)`

Answer (score 3):

The function `rollapply` in package `zoo` should do the trick:

```
library(zoo)
values = c(29.66, 29.59, 30.05, 29.59, 29.59, 30.05, 29.59, 29.92, 30.26, 30.18, 30.47)

rollmax(values, k=3)
# or
rollapply(values, 3, max)

# [1] 30.05 30.05 30.05 30.05 30.05 30.05 30.26 30.26 30.47
```

Comment: thanks a lot Hong and Matt! However...i got error message. Error in UseMethod("rollapply") : 
  no applicable method for 'rollapply' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Comment: Hi matt...sorry. I got it! Updated my zoo package and everything is fine. Thanks a lot buddy.

Comment: @user1101736: Your welcome, consider accepting one of the answers ;)