# Using matrix column or rows to reference elements of a vector

Tags: r

I have a vector. I select groups of n=4 consecutive values using the matrix produced by `mapply(seq,starts,ends)`.  I use the matrix columns to reference elements in my vector `y`. Then I run the `min` function on the sub vectors to identify the minimum value in each group of elements.

```
set.seed(30)
y <- sample(100)
  # [1]  10  49  36  41  29  15  85  21  89  13   6  98  48  77  20  79  22  69
 # [19]  50  35  91  47   3  26  86  23  92  19  59  34  43  17  71  97  76  44
 # [37]  90  87  78  83  27  37  45  28  11  38  70  95  99   9   7  51  53  66
 # [55]   4  40   5  46  25  81   2  54  57  93  55  84  61  82  73  31  96  58
 # [73]  68  74  32 100  24  72   1  30  39  42  16  14  64  75  67  60  56  33
 # [91]  94  88  65   8  52  12  80  63  62  18
x <- c(3,6,9,14,17,21,23)
ends <- x*4
starts <- ends - 3
m <- mapply(seq,starts,ends)
     # [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
# [1,]    9   21   33   53   65   81   89
# [2,]   10   22   34   54   66   82   90
# [3,]   11   23   35   55   67   83   91
# [4,]   12   24   36   56   68   84   92
```

For example, the first column in m is 9,10,11,12.  The goal is to reference the 9th through the 12th element of `y` and find out which of the 4 referenced element is the minimum. Then do the same thing with the rest of `m`'s columns, grouping `y`'s elements based on `m` columns.  I attempted to use the following code, but it didn't produce the expected results. Instead it produced all ones, and it was very slow.

```
oneU <- as.integer(sapply(m,function(i) which(y[i]==min(y[i]))))
```

The desired output is:

```
# [1] 3 3 4 3 1 4 2
```

Note for the first group the minimum should be the 3rd element of the group, which is the 11th element of `y`.

Is there an efficient way of employing matrix columns or rows to reference elements of a vector into groups, and then run a function on the resulting groups?

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532955/finding-maximum-value-in-column/8533044#8533044). Using `zoo::rollapply` should help you.

Comment: I am not scanning every three rows or n rows the starts can start anywhere its not the same as the question you referenced.  In addition I am trying to identify which element is the min not what is the min.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) tapply** Try this:

```
tapply(y[m], col(m), which.min)
```

**2) apply** or this:

```
apply(replace(m, TRUE, y[m]), 2, which.min)
```

**3) rollapply** or this:

```
library(zoo)
rollapply(y[m], nrow(m), which.min, by = 4)
```

**4) sapply**

```
sapply(as.data.frame(replace(m, TRUE, y[m])), which.min)
```

**ADDED** A few more solutions.

Comment: Tried to add it to my previous comment but was too late.  I am assuming one could use row(m) also for the second argument to solve other problems.  Meaning this solutions gives us the liberty to use the columns or rows of our matrix m to reference y elements. Is that right?  This could simplify many other issues I am facing in my project.

Comment: @user3507767, Its the same as `y[c(m)]` in this case.  Yes `row(m)` would aggregate by rows.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for `apply` to iterate over columns of a matrix, because by default `mapply` has `SIMPLIFY = TRUE` and returns a matrix. Either with the matrix `m` as stated:

```
oneU <- as.integer(apply(m,2,function(i) which(y[i]==min(y[i]))))
```

Or have `mapply` return a list, and then use `sapply` as you have written:

```
m <- mapply(seq,starts,ends, SIMPLIFY = TRUE)
```

For small enough vectors, I would use `zoo::rollapply` to compute the rolling minimum across the entire vector, and then subset the elements I want:

```
rollapply(y,4,which.min)[starts]
```